# Cannot ask for request attribute - request is not active anymore

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

In my application i am trying to make a request in a new thread which basically will fire and forget. But before the request is completed I guess the parent request is getting completed due to which the RequestAtrribute is getting invalid and I am getting the below error

Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot ask for request attribute - request is not active anymore!

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't just don't. Retrieve what you need from the request and pass it in an object to your async thread. Dn't try to extend the request lifecycle to another thread, it will only lead you down a dark path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to proxy your "Request Scope" bean.

So instead of using `@Autowired`, you will send the a bean clone to the async thread.

So instead of:

```
public class A {

  @Autowired private RequestScopeBean myBean;

  public void run() {
    myBean.stuff(); //Exception here.
  }
}
```

You will write:

```
public class A {
  public void run(RequestScopeBean beanProxy) {
    beanProxy.stuff();
  }
}
```

In the second case you instantiate RequestScopeBean manually and pass it.

I hope this is what you needed.

Comment: I am using request scope beans but the issue is even before the new thread is completed the parent thread is getting completed and the RequestAttributes is getting inactive.